# i want to install a ceiling fanlight without connecting it to the wall switch

Tags: electrical, light

i want to install a ceiling fanlight without connecting it to wall switch, but now that it is installed the ceiling fan light come on every time i turn on the light switch and I don't want that,please tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: You probably can't, but it depends on how the light was wired. Were there two or four wires in the ceiling box?

Comment: By light switch I suspect the one on the fan and not the switch on the wall. The problem of this is caused by incorrect wiring on the fan it self. You connected the FAN live to the Lights LIVE or something like that.. causing this issue. You need to seperate the LIVES

Comment: how do i seperate the LIVES?

Comment: there were four wires in the ceiling box a red ,black,white,and bare cooper wire

Comment: Post pictures of the junction box for the switch and the box for the fan, and post pictures of the wiring for the fan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both hots (red and black) in the light box are switched (probably--you haven't told us enough to know for sure). You could install a switch lock, or you could nut the two conductors that connect to the switch together and optionally install a blank switch plate.

Comment: Is this fan or the light controlled by a wall switch? or two wall switches? Or is there no wall switch and you don't want one, and you want to control both fan and light by pull chain switches in the unit?

Comment: Jim yes it is a two wall switch, One switch is for the can light going up the stairs and the other is for the other two ceiling lights at the top of the stairs in the loft area. i brought a ceiling fan tho with a light ,it has a remote so i dont need the wall switch for the ceiling fan but i still need the other light thats at the back of the loft

Answer (score 3):

Generally, installers assume that if you have a fan and light combo, you will want to control them separately.   That's what is happening when you see a cable coming from the light switch with red, black, white and bare.  Ground and neutral are shared, and the red and black give you 2 hots so you can control fan and light separately.

You can buy double switches which put 2 complete switches in the space normally taken by one.

Answer (score 2):

One way this could occur is if in the wall switch box, both the red and the black going to the fan/light unit are *both* connected to the load side of the same switch.

If that is the case and you want *only the light* to be controlled by the wall switch, then you would disconnect the fan hot (red or black) from the load side of the switch and leave the light hot connected to the switch. You would then connect the fan hot to the line (that feeds the line side of the switch) so power to the fan unit would be on all the time. You would then use the pull chain to switch the fan on and off.